# start a tmuxinator session on login

Tags: bash, bundler, gnome, tmux

I'd like to start a tmuxinator session when I login (Gnome on Ubuntu Lucid).
I've tried variations of the following but they all execute and close the terminal window.  The following have been given to 'Startup Applications'

```
sleep 10; /usr/bin/gnome-terminal --execute bash -c 'cd /src/thinit;exec bundle exec mux start thinit'
sleep 10; /usr/bin/gnome-terminal --execute bash -c 'cd /src/thinit;bundle exec mux start thinit'
sleep 10; /usr/bin/gnome-terminal --execute bash -c 'cd /src/thinit;exec bundle exec mux start thinit;exec bash'
```

Appreciate any insight.

Comment: I'd recommend asking on Super User.

Answer (score 0):

when you execute a shell with -c, it goes into *non-interactive* mode
move the stuff after -c to a script and execute the script itself instead of bash -c

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /src/thinit
bundle
mux start thinit
bash
```

and call it similarly (shown using environment variable for terminal and short option instead of long)

```
$TERM -e myscript
```